# PHP Mailer doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm working on a registration page on a website where I need to implement a email verification.

I have installed PHPMailer-master on the server. The first part of the code is written directly in the registration php:

```
include('send_mail.php');
    $to=$email;
    $subject="Email verification";
    $body='Hi, <br/> <br/> thank you for joining us! Please verify your email and get started using your account. <br/> <br/> <a href="'.$base_url.'activation/'.$activation.'">'.$base_url.'activation/'.$activation.'</a>';

    Send_Mail($to,$subject,$body);
    $msg= "Registration successful, a verification email has ben sent to you. Please activate this to get started.";
```

And the code in send_mail.php:

```
<?php
function Send_Mail($to,$subject,$body)
{
require 'PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$from       = "*mywebsite*";
$mail       = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(true);            // use SMTP
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Host       = "*my webhost's mailserver*"; // SMTP host
$mail->Port       =  465;                    // set the SMTP port
$mail->Username   = "*username*";  // SMTP  username
$mail->Password   = "*password*";  // SMTP password
$mail->SetFrom($from, '*mywebsite?*');
$mail->AddReplyTo($from,'*mywebsite?*');
$mail->Subject    = $subject;
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$address = $to;
$mail->AddAddress($address, $to);
$mail->Send(); 
}
?>
```

I'm fairly sure the information in send_mail.php is correct. I'm using the information I found on my configure mail client page on cPanel ("Secure SSL/TLS Settings").

When I try to register, the website goes white somehow. The account gets created on phpmyadmin. No error-log in public_html.

Any ideas?

UPDATE: Sorry for late response.

I've tried using the PHPMailer Test Page. When I try SMTP, the page just loads forever. When using Sendmail, I get the error "Could not execute: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i". When I use the QMAIL, it says the email was sent but I never recieve it.

BUT... when I use Mail, I recieve it successfully. Is "Mail" secure enough to use? What are the differences? And how should I implement it into the php code of the register page? I can't find any specific part in the PHPMailer Test Page code for the "mail" function.

Code looks like this now:

```
        $email = $_POST['email'];
require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';   
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
try {
$mail->AddReplyTo('myemail');
$mail->AddAddress($email);
$mail->SetFrom('myemail');
$mail->AddReplyTo('myemail');
$mail->Subject = 'subject';
$mail->Message = 'message comes here';
$mail->Send();
echo "Message Sent OK<p></p>\n";
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
echo $e->errorMessage();
} catch (Exception $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Error message: "Message body empty"

Comment: There's a built-in PHP mail function that might be easier: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: If you get a blank page, then something went wrong in your script. I suggest you start taking a look into your http servers error log file where php errors are logged to. There is little sense in trying to _guess_ what the issue might be, if you can instead look into that file and _read_ what the error actually _is_.

Comment: Apart from that, what is the sense behind these two lines: `$address = $to; $mail->AddAddress($address, $to);`? You specify the same address _twice_?

Comment: A white screen ususlly indicates a PHP error, which you will see either in your web server logs or on screen if you enable error display in your php.ini. I suggest you read the PHPMailer docs and start by using one of the examples bundled with PHPMailer since you've based your code on an obsolete example. Using mail() is a *very* bad idea if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: @arkascha - the line `$mail->AddAddress($address, $to);` used in the sample takes arguments of the display name and the to address. Here I guess saltcracker doesn't need to or want to know the person's real name, hence copying the address again into the display name. The MIME header line for this would simply read `To: john@smith.com <john@smith.com>`. While this may not be perfect from an UX point of view, it is perfectly valid from a PHPMailer point of view.

Comment: @saltcracker try `$mail->Body = 'message  comes here'` rather than `$mail->Message`

Comment: I ran into something yesturday similar to this. No white screen of death, but it was failing to send emails. 

If you specify a from address you MUST make sure $mail->Sender is set to the same from address otherwise the -f flag is never sent to mail() and the from header is malformed. Not normally a problem unless your using a service like Mailgun which is picky about headers.

Also, mail() is suppressed with an @ so you probably wont see any formatting errors...

Edit::: It was probably a couple of versions out of date, but worth confirming thats not the issue anyway.

Comment: @Skrrp Please don't link to obsolete examples, go directly [to the source](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)